# Access to heroku apps lost

Tags: heroku

I've lost access to Heroku apps that I created and are currently live

when I run 'heroku git:remote -a myappname' the response is

Error: You do not have access to the app myappname

```
    'heroku git:remote -a myappname'
```

Error: You do not have access to the app myappname

How can I restore access to my apps ?

Comment: This isn't the kind of thing that happens out of the blue, generally speaking. Did you change something? Transfer ownership of the apps in question? Get a new computer? Try contacting Heroku support.

Comment: All computer problems occur because something has changed. Asking what changed is like saying "where do you last see it ?" when you lose something. If I knew what changed then I could fix the problem.  Heroku recommends stackoverflow for support of free dynos.

Answer (score -1):

Might have to re-enter your Heroku login credentials.

Comment: This looks like a wild guess, not a comprehensive answer based on the information given by the OP. Once you have [earned 50 reputation points you will be able to cmment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), and that's where this kind of thing belongs. Until then, please earn reputation by asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your comment is not specific or helpful.  Usually people respond to questions because they have seen something similar or have a specific recommendation about how to fix the problem. It's appreciated that you comment but please try to avoid general statements like 'maybe you should reboot' or 'did you change something ?'